# Do views refresh if you reference them in a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, view

I created a view in SQL Server 2008.  It is the result set from joining two tables.

I am now running a query on another table that will have the following filter:

```
WHERE column_a NOT IN 
     (
     SELECT column_b
     FROM my_view
     )
```

Will this automatically regenerate the view so that column_b is up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, views are living things, with feelings too! :)

Comment: Excellent.  So the view will automatically re-run in realtime if I reference it in that subquery?

Comment: In short, a view is just a query stored in the system tables.  When you reference a view, the reference is replaced by the definition you stored.

Comment: Accept my answer if it's suitable. :) Thanks.

Comment: The exception is when the definition of a table referenced by the view changes, then you will need to do a refresh of the view to get the changes to propogate.